# pass httpheader to the conversationupdated event - directline

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Sending custom http header value while starting a conversation with the bot using DirectLine client. Was expecting it in the ConversationUpdate event in which I'm not able to finding it in the Request.Headers["userName"]

```
 headers.Add("userName", name);
        var conversation = await directLine.Conversations.StartConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync(headers);
```

Comment: Headers are stripped out as the pass through the connector service. Have you tried using channeldata to pass the userName?

Comment: Thank you so much Eric. I was not aware of it, are there any sample on how to use channel data while starting a new conversation? My intention is getting the username to send welcome message to the user by wishing using his name. Using the conversation updated message type.

Comment: Also, what is the usage of StartConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync if it strip out the http header values ?directLine.Conversations.StartConversationWithHttpMessagesAsync(httpHeader)

Comment: I agree.  I've escalated your question, and I'm awaiting a response.

Comment: Thank you Eric, appreciate it 

Answer (score 0):

The `customHeaders` parameter is automatically included in the client when generated by autorest, but it is not being used.

Initiating a direct line conversation with a specified `from.Name` is currently a prioritized backlog item.

I'm sorry these are not the answers you're looking for.